# MYSQL if/else clause

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I need to do a such thing in SQL but I don't know how...

```
IF *row exists* THEN  
  UPDATE ...
ELSE
 CREATE ...
```

I can't figure how to do that..

Comment: Your question is very undefined.  Is this if a record already exists in a table then update the record; or is it create a table if the table doesn't exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE....` or `REPLACE` should do the trick:

ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

REPLACE
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

Comment: INSERT INTO lang (ip, lang) VALUES('$ip', 'fr') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE SET lang='fr' WHERE ip='$ip';  This doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @user576488, this should be `INSERT INTO lang (ip, lang) VALUES('$ip', 'fr') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE lang='fr'`.  This also requires a collision of the unique keys on the table.  What's your table structure look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a normal insert statement with a `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` described in the docs :

here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert.html